# "They went for one- fifty if they went for a quarter"

Tags: meaning, expressions

They in this sentence refers to:

> "worked leather cowboy boots studded with silver conches".

What does the phrase in the topic mean? The boots could sell for 6 times as much now because of the silver?

EDIT: I don't seem to have enough to comment on the commentators below, so I will ask my follow-up here.

Does this mean the last part of the sentence

> "...if they went for a quarter"

only serves to clarify the unit mentioned in the beginning (in this case, money) and not about any cost (a quarter)?

Comment: I googled the title but could not find a corresponding book. Could you please provide a little more context to help?

Comment: It's from the book "The Name of the Game is Death" by Dan J. Marlowe.

Comment: Possibly one-fifty meant $150...back then they would have said "a buck fifty" for $1.50.

Comment: I suspect it means they cost *at least* 150. Hard to be sure without seeing the sentence in context.

Comment: I think it's a figure of speech. You sometimes hear expressions like "It's ten feet long if it's an inch."

Comment: This saying can be  used to counter a statement by another person, who says/guesses  the boots sold for a quarter. Then the speaker says, I disagree: if they went for a quarter (as you say), then I say they actually  went for a $1.50.

Comment: @Clare—Exactly right to my ear. If those boots are worth anything at all, even 25 cents, I will bet that they cost at least 150 dollars.  Meaning, in any real sense, those boots are quite valuable.I don't think there is an argument about whether the boots would actually sell for coins, but as a mark of derision: If I told you once, I told you a thousand times—You think the boots are trash? I say worth a great deal.